# Read.csv outputs factors instead of numeric values

Tags: r, csv

I am writing an R code that automatically extracts an enormous amount of data from different .csv files and
"compiles" the data in long panel data format. Below is a snippet of the code for the census variable "Race":

```
    for (i in 1:10) {
  dat.race <- read.csv(files.race[i], header = TRUE, sep = ",")
  dat.race <- cbind(2004 + i, dat.race[-1, c(2:4, 6, 8, 16)])  #Create a column with the year (each file corresponds to a diff. year)
  if (i == 1) {
    race <- dat.race
  } else {
    race <- rbind(race, dat.race[, names(race)])
  }
 }
```

The code's purpose is to go into the folder, open each of the 10 files in the folder "Race" (each file has one year
values for the 50 US States, and we have 10 years of data for 2005-2014, thus the 10 files) extract the necessary columns (all files come from the census.gov website, therefore the setup is the same) which we
manually input, and then compile them all together (so we go from 10 files with 10 years of data to just 1 file).

This worked well for all the variables. But then we arrived to the variable population density. Since we didn't find
population density we figured we would get the population variables and then the state area variables and do a simple
division in R. But then we found out that the read.csv command had extracted our comma-separated values into factors,
which we cannot use for mathematical operations.

I tried the as.numeric() command but it returns the number of the factor rather than the original number (not sure if that makes complete sense). I also tried
some of the solutions that other users have posted, to no avail.

Does anyone know how to make it so that the above code provides us with numeric values which we can then use to
make operations, rather than do it hand by hand?

Update: after using the suggestion from cryo111, I now have a data frame of 7 columns and 520 rows (just for the variable race), and the data is organised as follows.

```
year GEO.id2 GEO.label total white black other
2005 01      Alabama   ....  ....  ....  ....
2005 02      Alaska    ....  ....  ....  ....
2005 04      Arizona   ....  ....  ....  ....
... ....     ....      ....  ....  ....  ....
2005 56      Wyoming   ....  ....  ....  ....
```

The idea is then to operate within the R code to calculate variables such as "Percentage of the population of Alabama that is white, etc" using the different values (white/total, etc.).

Unfortunately when I look at the components (race[5,1]) for example, it returns "character". And if I proceed to use as.numeric() it returns the error "Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'"

Any help is super appreciated!

Comment: What does this have to do with Python?

Comment: Try `read.csv(files.race[i], header = TRUE, sep = ",",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`.

Comment: @cryo111 Thanks for the reply. That was one of the options I found on the forums beforehand; I apologise that I was not clear enough. This works to put the data into a data frame, but when I try to add two columns `c <- race$caucasian + race$nativeamerican` I get the error "Non-numeric argument to binary operator".

Comment: @Manuel It somehow happened that you have lists stored as data.frame elements. Like that `x=data.frame(a=1);x$b=list(1:2);as.numeric(x$b)`. Can it be that the csv file is malformed?

Comment: Hi @cryo111, we managed to solve it.  Thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We managed to solve it. Apparently, from the raw .csv data file, one of the read.csv options is to determine how many rows to skip and whether the header was present.

If we used the header = TRUE command, it kept the header as a factor. That is probably why we could not force it through as.numeric.

What we did was 2 read.csv: the first for the data, and the second for the headers. We then combined both of them and it worked.